# Python ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working through a book named 'Mastering Python Data Analysis' and I am getting an error on one the data modeling exercises. The error I am getting is:

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

I am not sure what this error means or what is causing it.

The code is as follows:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import numpy.random as rnd
import scipy.stats as st

mean = 0
sdev = 1
nvalues = 10
norm_variate = mean * sdev +rnd.randn(nvalues)
print(norm_variate)

for i, v in enumerate(sorted(norm_variate), start = 1):
    print(('{0:2d} {1:+.4f}' .format(i,v)))

def plt_cdf(data, plot_range=None, scale_to=None, **kwargs):
    num_bins = len(data)
    sorted_data = np.array(sorted(data), dtype=np.float64)
    data_range = sorted_data[-1] - sorted_data[0]
    counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(sorted_data, bins=num_bins)
    xvalues = bin_edges[:1]
    yvalues = np.cumsum(counts)
    if plot_range is None:
        xmin = sorted_data[0]
        xmax = sorted_data[-1]
    else:
            xmin, xmax = plot_range
            # pad the arrays
            xvalues = np.concatenate([xmin, xvalues[0], xvalues, [xmax]])
            yvalues = np.concatenate([[0.0, 0.0], yvalues, [yvalues.max()]])
            if scale_to is not NONE:
                yvalues = yvalues / len(data) * scale_to
                plt.axis([xmin, xmax, 0, yvalues.max()])
                return plt.plt(xvalues, yvalues, **kwargs)

nvalues = 20
norm_variate = rnd.randn(nvalues)
plt_cdf(norm_variate, plot_range=[-3,3], scale_to=1.0, lw=2.5, color='Brown')
for v in [0.25, 0.5, 0.75]:
    plt.axhline(v, lw=1, ls='--', color='black')
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the variables in the concarenate expressions.  Are they arrays?  Or scalars (which evaluate as zero dimensiona, arrays?  Keep the numpy docs at hand, especially if your book isn't careful with the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a simple array, and a couple of scalar values:

```
In [197]: x = np.arange(4)
In [198]: x0=x[0]; x1=x[-1]
```

trying to join them produces your error:

```
In [199]: np.concatenate([x0, x, x1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-199-9131e46a3dcd>", line 1, in <module>
    np.concatenate([x0, x, x1])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

But adding [] to define lists, and hence 1 element arrays, works:

```
In [200]: np.concatenate([[x0], x, [x1]])
Out[200]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3])
```

`hstack` does the same thing - turning any scalars in to arrays

```
In [201]: np.hstack([x0,x,x1])
Out[201]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3])
```

Keeping track of dimensions is an important part of using `numpy`.  Don't make assumptions.  Especially when there are errors, test, and test again.