# When I want to pass the tf-idf vectorize data and numeric data at the same time in the fit() of machine learning model why does this error arised?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I want to combine text and numeric feature same time for duplicate question pair detection. But when I pass the data to the classififer.fit()

> setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.

error occured. How can I solve this? The snippet of code:

```py
        from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

        X=train_df.drop(['is_duplicate', 'Unnamed: 0', 'id', 'qid1', 
       'qid2','word_mover_distance','jaccard_sim'],  axis=1)
        y=train_df['is_duplicate'].values

        X_num = train_df[['word_mover_distance', 'jaccard_sim']].values
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        X_num = scaler.fit_transform(X_num)

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
        X_num_train, X_num_test = train_test_split(X_num, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
        from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

        tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents=None,
                       lowercase=True,
                       preprocessor=None, # applied in Data Cleaning
                       use_idf=True,
                       norm='l2',
                       smooth_idf=True
        train_q1 =tfidf.fit_transform(X_train['question1'])
        train_q2 =tfidf.fit_transform(X_train['question2'])

        from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
        log_clf = LogisticRegression(C=0.5, max_iter=1000)
        log_clf.fit([train_q1,train_q2, X_num_train],y_train) #Error arise here
```

Comment: There are several problems with your code: first you use `fit_transform` twice, this is a mistake because (1) it will cause different indexings for the vocabulary in the 2 questions, (2) you cannot reuse the same vocab later for the test set. But even if the 2 questions are provided correctly to LR, this method cannot work because LR doesn't have any way to compare different features among themselves. The design is wrong, this problem is more complex than you realize, I'm afraid. Since this is about design, if you want you can ask on datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You might be interested in [record linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage) and *deduplication*.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression `.fit()` method expects (from documentation):

> X{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)

Passing features as list of array leads to fact that shape of X becomes [3, n_samples, n_features] and this is why it is not working.

You can try wrapping your list with `np.concatenate()` to avoid this problem.

Comment: ```X_train = np.concatenate((train_q1, train_q2, X_num_train), axis=0)``` I want to do it but it generates the folowing error. Will you help me to solve this? I am beginner in this field. error, ```zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated```

Comment: Check shape of each variable - it seems that one of them is just a value (I have reproduced this error using this piece of code: `np.concatenate([5, X, X])`)

Comment: You also can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434317/19533532)